# Sliding Drawer Application Exiting

Tags: android

For my application I need to create a sliding drawer for groups of button, but when I run the code it shows force to close warning..My Xml look like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout
       android:visibility="visible"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <com.measure.sizemesurment2.MyView
     android:id="@+id/DrawViewId"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </com.measure.sizemesurment2.MyView >

    <SlidingDrawer
      android:id="@+id/drawer"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:handle="@+id/handle"
      android:content="@+id/content">

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:src="@drawable/drawer"/>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="bottom">



  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"                    
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"                    
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" 
        android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"                                   
        android:src="@drawable/up" />

      <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/down"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"   
         android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"                    
         android:src="@drawable/down" />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"  
        android:textSize="20dp"  
        android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"              
        android:text="+" 
      />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/minus"
       android:layout_width="40dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
       android:textSize="20dp"  
       android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"                    
       android:text="-" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/ok"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"  
      android:textSize="20dp"  
      android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"                        
      android:text="OK" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </SlidingDrawer>

  </FrameLayout>
```

where MyView class used for canvas drawing..
Am right in the case of above xml file...Any help will be appreciated.....
Thanks in advance.....

here is my logcat

```
10-22 17:40:17.810: D/dalvikvm(6384): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 44% free   3371K/5959K, external 1801K/1925K, paused 31ms
10-22 17:40:17.860: I/Camera(6384): handleMessage: 16
10-22 17:40:17.952: I/Camera(6384): handleMessage: 16
10-22 17:40:17.979: I/Sample::Activity(6384): onPause
10-22 17:40:17.979: I/Sample::SurfaceView(6384): releaseCamera
10-22 17:40:18.017: D/IPCThreadState(6384): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x1772a0
10-22 17:40:18.193: D/AndroidRuntime(6384): Shutting down VM
10-22 17:40:18.194: W/dalvikvm(6384): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b6a8)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.measure.sizemesurment2/com.measure.sizemesurment2.MesureSizeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The content attribute is must refer to an existing child.
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1740)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1759)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:999)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3826)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The content attribute is must refer to an existing child.
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.widget.SlidingDrawer.onFinishInflate(SlidingDrawer.java:277)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:662)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:439)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:351)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:307)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:253)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1703)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.measure.sizemesurment2.MesureSizeActivity.onCreate(MesureSizeActivity.java:55)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1704)
10-22 17:40:18.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     ... 11 more
10-22 17:40:18.203: E/dalvikvm(6384): [DVM] mmap return base = 45374000
10-22 17:40:18.246: D/dalvikvm(6384): GC_CONCURRENT freed 442K, 48% free 3139K/6023K, external 1206K/1925K, paused 2ms+17ms
```

Comment: -1 for not posting stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare

```
   android:id="@+id/content"
```

for RelativeLayout in your SlidingDrawer.
You can find more information about SlidingDrawer from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)
If it doesn't work then, post logcat here.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I gave an id for my relative layout and now it's working......

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that in the class com.measure.sizemesurment2.MyView  you have the following constructor

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
    //your code
}
```

Thanks & Regards,
Rajamanickem.S

Comment: Yes it is working without drawer....

Comment: Have a look at the example in the following example...   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/SethandleandcontentforSlidingDrawer.htm